# How to use RackUnit to check for an error?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, lisp, racket, htdp

I have the following [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) code.

```lisp
#lang racket

(require rackunit racket/exn)

(define (string-last s)
  (let ((lng (string-length s)))
    (substring s (- lng 1) lng)))

(string-last "")
(check-equal? (string-last "1") "1")
(check-equal? (string-last "testing") "g")
```

The call of string last with an empty string fails as expected with:

```
--------------------
. ERROR
name:       check-exn
location:   014.rkt:12:0

substring: contract violation
  expected: exact-nonnegative-integer?
  given: -1
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   ""
   0
--------------------
```

How to check for the error by using [RackUnit](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/) library?

I tried

```lisp
(check-exn exn:fail? (string-last ""))
```

and several other variants in place of `exn:fail?` but I didn't manage to find the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check-exn` needs a function of no arguments – a thunk – it can call which should raise the exception.  So the right incantation would be

```
(check-exn exn:fail? (thunk (string-last "")))
```

It must be passed a thunk because otherwise the default evaluation order of Racket would mean that the exception is raised *before* the function is called, so it never gets to catch it.